# Object instantiation using eval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constructor, eval

Short question, if this works (and it does):

```
eval("new " + generator.className + "(" + generator.constructorArgs.join(", ") + ")");
```

why doesn't this work:

```
eval(generator.className + ".prototype.constructor.apply({}, generator.constructorArgs);");
```

The second expression always returns undefined, but in my opinion it should work. I tried it on dummy objects like:

```
var dummy = function () {};
```

Also, is there any way I can avoid using eval in this situation?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think the problem is that your constructor function is not returning anything.

When you use the `new` operator, if the constructor function, does not return an object, the `this` value, which is the newly created object is returned implicitly, for example:

```
function Foo () {
  this.foo = 'bar';
}

new Foo(); // { foo: 'bar' }
```

If you invoke the function with call/apply, it will yield `undefined`, since there is no return value at all:

```
Foo.call({}); // undefined
```

So, the solution would be to return the `this` value on your constructor, e.g.:

```
function Bar() {
  this.bar =  'baz';
  //..
  return this;
}

Bar.call({}); // { bar: 'baz' }
```

Also, remember that using the `new` operator is not completely equivalent to *apply* a function using a new object as the `this` value, because when you use the `new` operator, the newly created object will *inherit* from its constructor's prototype, e.g.:

```
new Bar() instanceof Bar; // true
Bar.call({}) instanceof Bar; // false
```

Comment: Also, `Foo.prototype.constructor` seems redundant and error prone to me, since the `constructor` property is mutable, and I think you want to invoke always the *generator.className* function...